# Meteor Collection Transform checking other Collections, strange behaviour

Tags: meteor

Meteor collection 'Client' is parent of collection 'Projects'
foreign key in Projects is 'client_id'.

Now I want to have the Projects collection extended with the Client name. If there is no Client-parent, then make Client name 'XXX'. 
(Easy to see the 'orphaned' projects: Just take those with XXX as Client name)

Meteor code is as follows:

**collections.js**

```
Client = new Mongo.Collection('clients');

Project = new Mongo.Collection('projects', {
        transform: function (doc) {

            var client = Client.findOne({"_id":doc.client_id},{"_id":0, "name":1});
            if (!client) {
                // Client name is 'XXX'
                return _.extend(doc, {"client_name":"XXX"});
            } else {
                return _.extend(doc, {"client_name":client.name});
            }

        }
    }
);
```

**publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('clientNewYork', function () {
    // This publication only New York clients, and only the name.
    return Client.find({"city":"New York"}, {fields: {"name": 1}}, {sort: name: -1});
});
Meteor.publish('projects', function () {
    return Project.find();
});
```

**subscriptions.js**

```
Meteor.subscribe('clientNewYork');
Meteor.subscribe('projects');
```

Application starts with first subscription: A list of all Clients in New York. 
Next screen is all Projects, enriched with Client name. 
Important: ALL projects, not only the ones from New York Clients.

**Weird thing happening:**

All projects of Clients not in New York get 'XXX' as Client name. 
That means that the publication is taken into account in the transform of the collection.

**My suspicion:**

The non New York clients are just not in the MiniMongo in my browser. 
But I expect that the collection.js goes to the database running on the server instead of the minimongo on the browser.

**Workaround:**

Change the client pubication to all clients instead of only New York ones. 
But my feeling says this is not good.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Transforms are run on a document whenever it is fetched. Your suspicion is correct:

When the project documents are fetched on the client, they each look for a corresponding client document. Because a `find` on the client will hit minimongo, only published clients (in your case NYC clients) will be matched.

Without knowing more about your implementation details it's hard to suggest a precise solution. Some options include:

1. Denormalize the data by storing the `client_name` field on the project (avoid the transform). The downside is that whenever you update a client's name, you will also need to update the corresponding project(s). Have a look at [collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks).
2. Have a more flexible publish function for clients. If you could identify the current project or the current set of projects, you could pass an id or an array of ids to the publish function when subscribing. In this way, you could still join the two collections without publishing the entire set of client documents.